# The cases for a hyperbola were a=c or a > c?

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections

Is it possible in the standard equation of a hyperbola with center at origin to have a=c or a > c , keeping in mind that if a=c then $b^2 = c^2 - a^2 =0$ which means $y^2 / b^2$ would  be undefined. And if a > c then $b^2 = c^2 - a^2$ would be negative which is impossible for a square.
If there are cases of hyperbolas where a=c or a > c then what are their equations? Are they still described by $x^2/a^2 - y^2/b^2 $?

i am refering for c that is $c^2 = a^2 + b^2$, i am looking for cases where a>c because as i was reading the derivation of the hyperbola equation b was defined such that $b^2 = c^2 - a^2$ which requires c > a or else $b^2$ will be negative (not possible) or will be 0 (then $y^2/b^2$ is undefined). However as i was searching the internet i saw that it's possible in the case of degenerate hyperbola to have a=c so i am confused.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degenerate_conic#Examples

Comment: Intelligenti pauca i looked at that link but can you provide a short answer to my question ?

Comment: If you're referring to the equation $\frac{x^2}{a^2} - \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1$, there is no $c$ in the equation. In a diagram where $a$ is the semi-major axis and $b$ the semi-minor axis, the distance from the center to a focus is often labeled $c$. Is that what you refer to? Why are you looking for cases where $a\geq c$? You can edit the question to improve it.

Comment: Davik K thank you very much for replying yes  yes i am refering for c that is c^2 = a^2 + b^2, i am looking for cases where a>c because as i was reading the derivation of the huperbola equation b was defined such that b^2 = c^2 - a^2 which requires c > a or else b^2 will be nagative(not possible) or will be 0(then y^2/b^2 is undefined). However as i was searching the internet i was that it's possible in the caee of degenerate hyperbola to have a=c so i am confused.

Comment: If you have extra information, please edit it into the question; do not put it in comments. Such information might include a link to wherever it was that gave you the idea that $a=c$ in a degenerate hyperbola. The usual concepts of semi-major axis and focus don't translate well to a degenerate conic.

Comment: David K okay i added the extra ingo to the question.

Comment: You still have not shared any motivation for why we should consider the symbol $c$ to have any meaning at all. I can write lots and lots of other equations involving $a$ and $b$, but I don't expect all of them to have meaning for a hyperbola, let alone for a degenerate hyperbola. We also still have no idea where you found anything on the internet saying that $a=c$ is possible in a degenerate hyperbola.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too long for a comment:

- All [hyperbolas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbola) are described by the equation $\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1\,.$
- Quite obviously, this equation has real solutions only when
  $$
  x^2=a^2\frac{b^2+y^2}{b^2}\ge a^2\,.
  $$
- In your notation $c^2=a^2+b^2$ we can plug $y=c$ into this inequality and write it as
  $$
  c^2\ge b^2\,.
  $$
- In other words: there is no real $a$ that is greater than $c\,.$ The case $a=c$ leads to $b=0\,.$ In that case the equation for
  the hyperbola is undefined. What might help is to consider
  the limit $b\to 0\,.$ The hyperbola then converges to the set
  $$
  \{x^2\ge a^2,y=0\}\,.
  $$

Comment: I just found a two-ray "hyperbola" [here](https://www.onemathematicalcat.org/Math/Precalculus_obj/hyperbolas.htm). Even the author of the page doesn't seem to consider it an actual hyperbola (degenerate or otherwise), however.

Comment: @DavidK In fact, it is not two points. I have updated the answer. How this is called doesn't really matter much to me.